# Warning: You did not close a PDF Document looping when renderImageWithDPI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pdf, pdfbox

i want to split pdf to image file by page, but i got Warning: You did not close a PDF Document looping when renderImageWithDPI
Still have warning
UPDATE CODE :

```
    public void splitImage(PDDocument document, File checkFile, File theDirSplit, String fileExtension, File theDir, File watermarkDirectory, int numberOfPages)
            throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {

        String fileName = checkFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "");
        int dpi = 300;
        if (theDirSplit.list().length < numberOfPages)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; ++i)
            {       
                if (i == numberOfPages)
                    break;
                
                if (theDirSplit.list().length != numberOfPages)
                {
                    File outPutFile = new File(theDirSplit + Constan.simbol + fileName + "_" + (i + 1) + "." + fileExtension);
                    document = PDDocument.load(checkFile);
                    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
                    BufferedImage bImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, dpi, ImageType.RGB);
                    ImageIO.write(bImage, fileExtension, outPutFile);
                                            
                }
                // splitService.watermark(outPutFile, (i + 1), watermarkDirectory, "pdf");
            }
            document.close();
            //System.out.println("Converted Images are saved at -> " + theDirSplit.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        System.out.println("Done Partial SPlit");
        /*
         * int i = 1; while (iterator.hasNext()) { PDDocument pd = iterator.next();
         * pd.save(theDirSplit + Constan.simbol + i++ + ".pdf"); }
         * System.out.println("Multiple PDF’s created");
         */

    }
```

[error looping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxF55.jpg)

total warning same with number of pages...
i already try to close but not work, this process make my server java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

update :

```
        else if ("pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(typeFile)) {
            System.out.println(
                    "target file " + downloadPath + R_OBJECT_ID + Constan.simbol + R_OBJECT_ID + "." + typeFile);
            
            //get jumlah halaman
            try(PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(checkFile)){
                File theDirSplit = new File(theDir.getAbsolutePath() + Constan.simbol + "splitImage");
                createFolder(theDirSplit);
                String fileExtension = "jpeg";
                File watermarkDirectory = new File(theDir.getAbsolutePath() + Constan.simbol + "watermarkImage");
                createFolder(watermarkDirectory);
                // split 2 page image
                if (theDirSplit.list().length <= document.getNumberOfPages()) {
                    try {
                        splitImage(document,checkFile, theDirSplit, fileExtension, theDir, watermarkDirectory, document.getNumberOfPages()/2);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR SPLIT PDF " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                res.setTotalPages(document.getNumberOfPages());
                document.close();
                return new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        } else {
            res.setTotalPages(1);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

this is code to call split method....

Comment: What version are you using? Is this the actual code, or do you have "new PDDocument()" somewhere else? Can you use try-with-resources?

Comment: i using pdfbox 2.0.16 , i already close PDDocument() in another method,but when i split the pdf the warning coming...

Comment: what do you mean with try-with-resources?

Comment: try-with-resources is a syntax used in jdk7 and higher (google for it). You mention split - you need to close the source document too and all split results (that code is missing). And the current version is 2.0.20.

Comment: `BufferedImage bImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, dpi, ImageType.RGB);
 ImageIO.write(bImage, fileExtension, outPutFile);` this code i use to split the pdf to jpeg....ok i'll try to update the pdfbox

Comment: All the documents in `List<PDDocument> Pages` need to be closed after you're done with them.

Comment: i already use try-with-resource doesn't that mean the `try(PDDocument document= PDDocument.load(checkFile))` autoclose after use it, or i should use document.close() in try block

Comment: You can't use try-with-resources with `List<PDDocument> Pages`, you'll have to close them individually after done.

Comment: i no longer use `List<PDDocument> Pages` to get the pages i use `document.getNumberOfPages()` but still there are warning, i have no idea why, i already close every document everytime i use it

Comment: But if you are calling "splitter.split()", this produces documents. These must be closed. Please edit your question to show the actual code used.

Comment: i already update....the code...but still get warning

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Are you sure that the new version is running? And that no other PDFBox application is running on that server? If yes, then please create a self-working non tomcat project that shows the problem. Btw your current code closes the same document 3 times.

Comment: I already fix the code and the warning not show anymore, thank you for helping me... I hope my server not get Java heap anymore in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat lost from the question, but the cause was failing to close the documents generated by splitter.split().